# How can I group newest records if there are any?

Tags: sql-server

let's imagine I have a table like

```
name     time_stamp             quantity
John     2017-11-28 08:46:01    65
Clark    2017-11-28 08:44:08    98
John     2017-11-28 08:50:54    74
```

and what I need is, to group it by name, and have data from the newest record. I can't do it like group by name, because the pc doesn't know what data it should use for John. I need the output like

```
name     time_stamp             quantity
Clark    2017-11-28 08:44:08    98
John     2017-11-28 08:50:54    74
```

because 65 is older record then 74..

I tried `SELECT name, MAX(time_stamp) AS time_stamp, quantity FROM table1 GROUP BY time_stamp` but it doesn't work for me because -

> Column 'table1.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [name] ORDER BY time_stamp DESC) AS RN
    FROM YourTable)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a derived table to select the max(time_stamp).

```
SELECT T1.*
  FROM (
         SELECT [name]
               ,MAX(time_stamp) AS MAXtime_stamp  --MAX time_stamp by name
           FROM table1
         GROUP BY [name]
       ) AS dT INNER JOIN table1 T1 ON dT.MAXtime_stamp = T1.time_stamp 
                                   AND dT.[name] = T1.[name]
```